# loop through if, return if false, if true => stop if

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, if-statement

So I got the following scenario:

```
$('.menu').find('a').each( function(el, val) {
  if( window.location.hash !== val.hash ) {
    $('.menu li').first().addClass('active') // we found no valid hash for us, so set first <li> active
    $('#hash1').show() // and show the first content
  } else {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active') // we found an hash, so give its parent <li> an active class
    $(window.location.hash).show() // can be #hash2, #hash3, whatever
    return false; // since we found something, stop the if.
  }
});
```

Well now obviously, each time we found no valid hash, we set the first element active and show the first content... but I dont want that.

I want the if to loop through all elements first before we go into the else statement.. and THEN if we found nothing, set the first element active and show the first content.

since I am looping through each "a", how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` to get the elements you want. If none are selected, you perform the default action:

```
var $links = $('.menu').find('a').filter(function() {
    return window.location.hash === this.hash;
});

if($links.length > 0) {
    $links.parent().addClass('active');
    $(window.location.hash).show();
}
else {
    $('.menu li').first().addClass('active');
    $('#hash1').show();
}
```

**Reference**: [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: Probably not, I'm sure `filter` is using `each` internally. I just think it's a bit cleaner as it avoids an additional flag.

Comment: just tested it on jsperf. there is almost no difference between them. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just keep a variable outside of the loop:

```
var found = false;

$('.menu').find('a').each( function(el, val) {
    if( window.location.hash === val.hash ) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active'); // we found an hash, so give its parent <li> an active class
        $(window.location.hash).show(); // can be #hash2, #hash3, whatever

        found = true;
    }
});


if(!found) {
    $('.menu li').first().addClass('active'); // we found no valid hash for us, so set first <li> active
    $('#hash1').show(); // and show the first content
}
```

Also, semicolons at the end of statements are *not* optional.

Comment: _"Also, semicolons at the end of statements are not optional."_ Yes they are. (Not in 100% of cases in JavaScript in general, but certainly in 100% of the statements in this code.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: I repeat, *not* optional. Yes, the interpreter will add them for you. Yes, it's "legal". It also makes for terrible code. Not optional ;)

Comment: http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699 "It is blatantly irresponsible of the thought leaders in the JavaScript community to continue to spread uncertainty rather than understanding."

Comment: seems like an undefined `this` in your `if' would be alot more of an issue than the semicolons

Comment: This still loops through the elements and shows the content of `#hash1` which is exactly what the OP does not want.

Comment: @FelixKling: See above comment.

Comment: So what you meant to say is "In my opinion semicolons should always be included"? (I always include them myself as a matter of style, but the rules for auto-insertion aren't that complicated so it doesn't bother me if other people leave 'em out.)

Answer (score 0):

If you could explain your requirement more clearly in English I think you'll find the JavaScript structure would follow naturally.

The following is my best guess at what you are trying to do: *All anchors in ".menu" that have the same `.hash` as `window.location.hash` should have their parent li made "active" and the corresponding element shown. If none matched then the first menu item should be made "active" and "#hash1" shown.*

```
var matched = false;
$('.menu').find('a').each( function(el, val) {
  if( window.location.hash === val.hash ) {
    matched = true;
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $(window.location.hash).show();
  }
});
if (!matched) {
    $('.menu li').first().addClass('active');
    $('#hash1').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elm = $(window.location.hash).length ? window.location.hash : '#hash1';
$(elm).show();
$('a[href$="'+elm+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
```

Assuming the markup is the same for `#hash1` as the rest, and that there is only one hash in the browser adress bar (or none) ?